# How can I open a link in new tab after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having the following scenario in React:

- I click on a button
- I make an ajax call, I get an url as response
- I want to open that url in a new tab without another click event

Is there a way I can do this in a single click event?

I tried the following code but no success:

```
return request(options, dispatch)
    .then(response => response.data.url ?
        (
            window.open(response.data.url, '_blank') 
        ) : (
            dispatch(updatedPage(id, response.data))
        )
    );
```

Cheers!

Comment: not react related, to open a link in new tab the action has to be in click handler to prevent pop-up. consider prefetching whatever data you need.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle example of the code https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I cannot prefetch any data because the ajax call sends quite a lot of data and i need that data to generate that link.

Comment: Whats the content of response.data.url? What's is the behavior you get when you try this?

Comment: response.data.url is a string of this format: 'http://example.com/myurl'

Comment: have you tried adding the protocol to the URI? If I try window.open('google.com', '_blank') in my browser console it opens the same page I'm in. If run window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')  it works as expected

Comment: looks like chrome blocked the popup (an icon will be shown in the address bar on the right), so u need to manually accept the popups on the server. seems to work. thanks guys.